# JS - Detect ActiveViewChanged using Word & Excel Online API

Tags: office-js

I am trying (for my first time) to develop Word & Excel Online add-in using JS and I want to trigger a custom functionality just before the document entering the 'Reading view' by detecting `Office.EventType.ActiveViewChanged`. AFAIK from the Office JS API documentation, this event is not yet supported in Word & Excel (only in PowerPoint), CMIIW. Is this true? Also it looks like we cannot manually trigger the active view mode. Any suggestion to make this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is only for PPT (and mostly used when to id when a slide show starts). Also, there is no API to trigger the view mode as of today. A good item to add to our [UserVoice site](http://officespdev.uservoice.com).

thanks!